# Our requirement is to fetch the data for code effects editor to be fetched from database using dotnetcore 3.0 and VueJs 2.0

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

We want to integrate code effects library in our project,We need the sample code for Vue.js 2.0 using typescipt and dotnet core 3.0.

Our requirement is to fetch the data for code effects editor to be fetched from database.

We noticed that the samples available in codeeffects with database support is in asp.net 4.0 Flexi Source,Can you please provide the Flexisource sample in .Net core 3.0 and Vuejs with typescript

Answer (score 0):

The client code of the rule editor is implemented as a stand-alone single object encapsulated in a separate class that can be instantiated and used on any client platform such as Vue, Angular, and so on. The same is with the rule engine which is delivered as a single .NET Standard 2.0 assembly that you can reference in any .NET code and use the same code samples provided in any of the demo projects available at [Code Effects documentation section](https://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Demo-Project) to evaluate your rules. There is no need to have a demo project for any possible client/server platform combination. Please ask here any question that is specific to your particular implementation of the Code Effects rules engine.